# Extract a number from comma separated string using regular expressions in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-substr

I am trying  to fetch a number which starts with 628 in a comma separated string. 
Below is what I am using:

```
SELECT 
    REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR('62810,5152,,', ',?628[[:alnum:]]+,?'),',','') first,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR('5152,62810,,', ',?628[[:alnum:]]+,?'),',','') second,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR('5152,562810,,', ',?628[[:alnum:]]+,?'),',','') third,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(',5152,,62810', ',?(628[[:alnum:]]+),?'),',','') fourth
FROM DUAL;
```

Its working but in one case it fails which is the third column where number is 562810. Actually I am expecting NULL in the third column.

Actual output from above query is:

```
"FIRST","SECOND","THIRD","FOURTH"
"62810","62810","62810","62810"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you are using `[[:alnum::]]`. You could use matching group to extract the number starting with 628 or followed by a comma. `REPLACE` may be avoided this way

If you have alphabets as well, modify the 2nd match group `()` accordingly.

```
SELECT 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('62810,5152,,' , '(^|,)(628\d*)',1,1,NULL,2) first,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('5152,62810,,' , '(^|,)(628\d*)',1,1,NULL,2) second,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('5152,562810,,', '(^|,)(628\d*)',1,1,NULL,2) third,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(',5152,,62810' , '(^|,)(628\d*)',1,1,NULL,2) fourth
FROM DUAL;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0ee9e/888)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your regex logic is that you are searching for an *optional* comma before the numbers `628`.  This means that any number having `628` anywhere would match.  Instead, you can phrase this by looking for `628` which is either preceded by either a comma, *or* the start of the string.

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR('62810,5152,,', '(,|^)628[[:alnum:]]+,?'),',','') first,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR('5152,62810,,', '(,|^)628[[:alnum:]]+,?'),',','') second,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR('5152,562810,,', '(,|^)628[[:alnum:]]+,?'),',','') third,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(',5152,,62810', '(,|^)(628[[:alnum:]]+),?'),',','') fourth
FROM DUAL
```

[image]

### Demo

The ideal pattern we'd like to use here is `\b628.*`, or something along these lines.  But Oracle's regex functions do not appear to support word boundaries, hence we can use `(^|,)628.*` as an alternative.